# Redirection error (Back to page)

Tags: php, redirect

I have a button which redirects you to the last page.

But when it goes to **news.php?page=1&search=s** I get an error.

The error looks like this http://i.gyazo.com/357a1bd5468a5e77a81ad53c7882093d.png

And the script.

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$('#back').on('click', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax/back.php',
        success: function(data) {
            var search = getUrlVars()['search'];
            if(typeof(search) === 'undefined') {
                window.location = "news.php?page="+data;
            } else {
                if(search.length > 0) {
                    window.location = "news.php?search="+search+"&page="+data;
                } else {
                    window.location = "news.php";
                }
            }
        }
    });
})
});
```

back.php

```
<?php

session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['last_page'])) {
    echo $_SESSION['last_page'];
} else {
    echo 1;
}
$_SESSION['last_page'] = array();

?>
```

Comment: you have a redirect loop. `a->a->a->...->a`, or `a->b->...->z->a->b-...` In your case: `news.php` -> `news.php?page=` -> `news.php` -> etc...

Comment: fix your logic so the script doesn't go into a loop.

Comment: so I have a news.php where you can see the latest news. And when you click an article it will open it, and there's a button called "back", which redirects you to the back page. It works fine when I'm on "news.php", but there's also search form, when you search something it goes to "news.php?search=example" and click an article. Then when you click the "back" button there, it should redirect to the last search.

Answer (score 0):

to go the back page change,

```
window.location = "news.php?search="+search+"&page="+data;
```

to

```
parent.history.go(-1);
```

Comment: But there's also a comment system in article. So when I type run this command, it will example go to page 2 of comments when you're in page 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found the loop.

news.php

```
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['page']);
    if($page < 1 || $page > $total_pages) {
        header("Location: news.php?page=1&search=$search");
    }
} else {
    $page = 1;
}
```

$total_pages = 2 (it depends on how much pagers I have, so 6 news each page and I have 8 so it's 2.

Comment: The $total_pages was in wrong place, that caused to keep the value 0, because of this the "header" was looping.